# RSpec tests for an invoice mailer

Tags: ruby, email, rspec

How would you DRY up this RSpec code?

```
require "spec_helper"

describe InvoiceMailer do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:student) { create(:student, user: user) }
  let(:body) { "And I for one will join with anyone, don't care what color you are. As long as you want change this miserable condition that exists on this earth." }
  subject(:mail) { InvoiceMailer.issue(student, body) }

  describe "issue" do
    subject(:mail) { InvoiceMailer.issue(student, body) }

    it "renders the subject" do
      expect(mail.subject).to eq "New Invoice!"
    end

    it "renders the receiver email" do
      expect(mail.to).to eq [student.user.email]
    end

    it "renders the sender email" do
      expect(mail.from).to eq ["info@test.com"]
    end
  end

  describe "rescind" do
    subject(:mail) { InvoiceMailer.rescind(student, body) }

    it "renders the subject" do
      expect(mail.subject).to eq "Invoice Rescinded!"
    end

    it "renders the receiver email" do
      expect(mail.to).to eq [student.user.email]
    end

    it "renders the sender email" do
      expect(mail.from).to eq ["info@test.com"]
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `its` syntax:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe InvoiceMailer do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:student) { create(:student, user: user) }
  let(:body) { "And I for one will join with anyone, don't care what color you are. As long as you want change this miserable condition that exists on this earth." }

  describe "issue" do
    subject { InvoiceMailer.issue(student, body) }

    its(:subject) { should eq "New Invoice!" }

    its(:to) { should eq [student.user.email] }

    its(:from) { should eq ["info@test.com"] }
  end

  describe "rescind" do
    subject { InvoiceMailer.rescind(student, body) }

    its(:subject) { should eq "Invoice Rescinded!" }

    its(:to) { should eq [student.user.email] }

    its(:from) { should eq ["info@test.com"] }
  end

end
```

You can further DRY it up using [example groups](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group)

```
describe InvoiceMailer do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:student) { create(:student, user: user) }
  let(:body) { "And I for one will join with anyone, don't care what color you are. As long as you want change this miserable condition that exists on this earth." }

  shared_examples_for "outgoing mail" do |method, mail_subject|
    subject { InvoiceMailer.send(method, student, body) }

    its(:subject) { should eq mail_subject }

    its(:to) { should eq [student.user.email] }

    its(:from) { should eq ["info@test.com"] }
  end

  describe "issue" do
    it_should_behave_like "outgoing mail", :issue, 'New Invoice!'
  end

  describe "rescind" do
    it_should_behave_like "outgoing mail", :rescind, 'Invoice Rescinded!'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I don't usually like `its` but in this case it's very readable. 

I feel like there is still a lot of duplication between the the `issue` and `rescind` describe blocks though. The only differences between the two are the methods on `InvoiceMailer` and the subject. Any thoughts?

Comment: Added an option with example groups

Comment: Oh! That's exactly what I was looking for!